# Is Karma part of Dharma? In other terms, is Karma a subset of Dharma?

Tags: karma, mahayana, dharmas

As per title.

I read the English translation of the heart sutra recently.If Karma is part of the Dharma, or is the Dharma, does this mean that Karma is not created or destroyed, and it neither decreases or increase, according to the heart sutra?

Answer (score 2):

Notice the Heart Sutra's subsequent sentences' explanation:

> **This is because in emptiness** there is no form, sensation, conception, synthesis, or discrimination. There are no eyes, ears, nose, tongue, body, or thoughts. There are no forms, sounds, scents, tastes, sensations, or dharmas. There is no field of vision and there is no realm of thoughts. There is no ignorance nor elimination of ignorance, even up to and including no old age and death, nor elimination of old age and death. There is no suffering, its accumulation, its elimination, or a path. There is no understanding and no attaining.

So does that mean there's no need to cultivate the Path because there is "no ignorance nor elimination of ignorance"; and actually no cultivation whatsoever because "there is no understanding and no Path"?? Of course not, the bolded part is the key point. Until one's penetrated that dimension/nature of emptiness, there is still ignorance to be eliminated, a Path to be cultivated, and wholesome and unwholesome Kammas to be decreased/increased, created/destroyed, etc.